# Huawei Push kit notification message group count related

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

In the guide of HMS Push notification, it is mentioned that **an app has one message group, which contains a maximum of 24 notification messages. Extra notification messages will be discarded.**
Does this mean that 25th message onwards will be discarded and never delivered?

**Link:** https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/push-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Please NOTE: here the message group is for one app on the device(phone, pad, etc). When the quantity greater than the maximum limit, the latter messages onwards will be discarded though it delivered to your devices.

The link used in the question is deprecated. Pls refer to the [latest guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040060):

For notification messages, note the following items:

•   An app has one message group with the upper limit. If the number of messages exceeds the upper limit, extra messages will be discarded (the upper limit is 24 for EMUI 10 and 11, and 49 for EMUI 9).

•   If a message group in the notification panel is collapsed, two messages in the message group and the number of remaining messages are displayed by default.
•   If a message group is expanded, a maximum of eight messages can be displayed.

[image]